# Rasterise a vector layer but relevant column is not numeric in QGIS

Tags: qgis, saga, rasterization

The software I'm using is QGis 3.16.0.

In order for a study project, I need to rasterise a vector layer (polygons) in order to classify certain classes of a certain attribute column with the process "Reclassify by table".

The attribute `COVERTYPE` consists of eight classes: `AGR`, `BAR`, `CON`, `HDW`, `MIX`, `SHB`, `URB` and `WAT`.

I tried to rasterise my vector field using the SAGA Tool "Rasterise". As "Attribute" I chose `COVERTYPE`, which is the correct one. For my other options please look at this screenshot:

[image]

Might there be any wrong settings in my configuration? I'm not that familiar with rasterising just yet...

For my rasterised layer, I just want to have eight different classes as well which I can classify then easily with the raster calculator. How do I know now, after I successfully rasterised my vector layer, which value represents which class?

By looking at the histogramm of my rasterised layer, there should be just eight different pixel values, instead I see many different pixel values, although my attribute covertype just has eight different classes. See also:
[image]

For your information, during the SAGA Rasterise process, there is the following warning: `selected attribute is not numeric; generating unique identifiers instead`. See also:

[image]

Could that be the problem? Firstly, do I have to give my attributes `AGR`, `BAR`, and so on numbers? That wouldn't quite be possible, because I have around 1000 objects...

Is there any other process which is better for my certain purpose? Unfortunately, the process "Rasterise (vector to raster)" doesn't even work, there is no output map.

Comment: "The software I'm using is the recent version of QGIS": always include the version number. There are at least two "recent" versions: the long term release LTR (3.10) and the newest (3.16), each of them having different point releases, at the moment (2021/01/15) 3.10.14 and 3.16.3  respectively, see: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html#release-schedule or on the upper left corner of https://qgis.org/

Answer (score 4):

**Update: How to solve your problem**

Inspecting your data, I discovered that there were no less than three (interconnected) problems (instead of one, as assumed previously) using SAGA `rasterize`. All have to do with the fact that the tool expects a certain kind of numerical input.

You can solve your problem in two ways: use GRASS `v.to.rast` (see bottom for this) or  continue to use SAGA `rasterize` by apply the following three measures:

1. Use a **numeric field** as input categories for rasterize, not a string (details how to create that in the next section)
2. Use **field type `integer 64 bit`** (qlonglong) for this numerical field. Using field type `integer` (int) as you had in your data did *not* produce the desired result (it created a diferent raster value for each feature).
3. Delete other fields from the attributes in `integer 64 bit` data type. In the file you provided, there was an `fid` field in `integer 64 bit` type. Only after deleting the `fid` (use: `Refactor fields`), SAGA rasterize runs as expected. However, you must use the temporary layer created by `Refactor fields`: if you save it as Geopackage file, it will automatically add another `fid` field.

**How to create a numerical input for rasterize**

As you guessed, the problem is that QGIS expects a numeric value as input to create raster values. The error message says that instead, for each feature (polygon) it creates another raster value. That is not what you want. Weird enough, SAGA rasterize seems to accept only integer 64 bit input. When the field you define as input has another type, the tool seems to use just another field for input with the "right" datatype, the `fid` in this case. So be sure to set the correct datatype (see screenshot).

Create a new field, a numeric code for your covertype: AGR=1, BAR=2, CON=3 etc. that you can use as `attribute` input in the rasterize dialog. Use field calculator with this expression to create an attribute `covertype_code`.

```
case 
when  "COVERTYPE" =  'AGR' then 1
when  "COVERTYPE" =  'BAR' then 2
when  "COVERTYPE" =  'CON' then 3
when  "COVERTYPE" =  'HDW' then 4
when  "COVERTYPE" =  'MIX' then 5
when  "COVERTYPE" =  'SHB' then 6
when  "COVERTYPE" =  'URB' then 7
when  "COVERTYPE" =  'WAT' then 8
end
```

[image]

---

**Alternative solution**

However, using the GRASS tool `v.to.rast` produced the desired result even with the original data you provided (as interger, not integer 64 bit), see screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I was looking for! But now, how do I know which spans of raster values represents which covertypes (numbers)? Do I need to order them in the Symbology, but according to which render type (maybe Singleband pseudocolour?) and which mode? Or do I just read the different covertypes out on the histogramm? See also: https://ibb.co/511zZ0H But how do I know, where one covertypes starts and where the next one ends on the histogramm in order to get the numbers for the raster classification?

Comment: QGIS assigns the number you have defined: see my answer: AGR will have raster value 1, BAR raster value 2 and so on. Or did I misunderstand your question? Singleband Pseudocolor would be a good choice (not the only one), you could use the viridis color palette and set the number of classes to 8 (or the number of covertypes you have).

Comment: See screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGwJX.png - the labels in the map canvas come from the polygon field `covertype_code`, but you see that the classes correspond to the ones in the raster. I selected pseudocolor. If you select grayscale, 1 (the smallest value) will be black, 8 (the highest value) will be white. If you select Paletted/Unique values, you can assign colors by hand.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not get these values from my rasterisation process... Instead, i get these if I Use Singleband Pseudocolour with 8 classes: https://ibb.co/pwXG8Pv Those classes are totally wrong... I also correctly added the new column "covertype_code"... see: https://ibb.co/GQ20GfR Maybe there are some wrong settings in my saga rasterise process? for this please see https://ibb.co/TTxyPXK Thanks so far again!! Maybe I also need to manually change the values of my raster in my symbology tab?

Comment: From the first screenshot it seems as if you had another field than `covertype_code` as input, however the last screenshot shows otherwise. Can you provide sample data? It's difficult to follow what you did/what went wrong when I use just random data.

Comment: Of course! Heres the sample data I need to rasterise: https://filehorst.de/d/difxEhoA

Comment: Maybe I need to use the Rasterise (vector to raster) instead of the SAGA Tool?

Comment: See updated answer: v.to.rast works. Don't know what's the issue with rasterize - used it today with ca. 150 features, grouped in 8 categories as described in my first answer, worked perfect. With your data, I got the different raster values for each feature - strange.

Comment: OK, I just successfully run rasterize tool, not sure yet what was the reason, will come back with more information.

Comment: You mean the Rasterize (vector to raster) tool? NOT the saga one?

Comment: It was a fieldtype issue, see details in the upadated solution. I always speak about the SAGA tool `rasterize`, the same that you used in your question/first screensot, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyTD6.png. The other solution (see the bottom of my answer) is the GRASS tool `v.to.rast`. So I'm confused which "Rasterize (vector to raster) tool,  NOT the saga" you mean? Anyway, bot SAGA (with datatype integer 64 bit) and GRASS (both datatypes) work, so you can choose :-)

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not working... My covertype_code is in Integer64, see: https://ibb.co/NZgRkcm  My raster layer gets the following wrong classes: https://ibb.co/P4LG38s and those (https://ibb.co/0sPR3Pr) are my settings regarding the SAGA rasterise process...

Comment: That's weird... Did you restart your computer? Maybe change all file- and field names to lowercase only, using only ASCII characters (you have a space in your layername). You're on windows, right? Strange, I used the same settings and it worked... Be sure to select the right layer and attribute field.

Comment: Im on windows, yeah. I did not restart it yet, but got the correct results now as well using v.to.rast, so I guess its okay. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I can see now: I tried it again and also had the problem you described. Only when I used the `Refactor fields` tool to delete the `fid` from the attributes, I was successfull. However, you can't save it as Geopackage, as the file format requires an fid field. So only when I ran `rasterize` on the temporary layer (without `fid`) did it work - as soon as I saved it to Geopackage (and an `fid` was added automatically), it behave as you described it.

Comment: Finally, how to solve the issue with the file you sent me:  
1. New project / open the file you sent me / field calculator: create new field `code` as `integer 64 bit` (copy from `covertype_code`) / save  ; -
2. `Refactor fields` / delete `fid` field / Run ; -
3. Use the temporary layer created in this way and run SAGA rasterize, input field: `code` from step 1